# How to use decimals in seaborn.distplot()?

Tags: python, seaborn

In my code, I am trying to learn distributions of data. My data is as follows:

```
18.86
19.86
18.98
18.31
18.76
17.78
17.05
16.75
...
```

Is there a way to plot these values as distplot() only accepts slices and ints?

Comment: Have you tried `df = pd.DataFrame({'MyData': [18.86,19.86,18.98,18.31,18.76,17.78,17.05,16.75]});  sns.distplot(df)` ?? You should use `displot()`, but above should work

Comment: This is working as well:
`sns.distplot([17.05,16.75,18.31,17.78,18.98,19.86])  plt.show()`

Comment: **as distplot() only accepts slices and ints** doesn't make any sense. `distplot` works fine with floats. Additionally, `distplot` is deprecated. You should update seaborn and use `histplot`, which also works with floats. I'm voting to close this because the question lacks clarity and sufficient details to be answered without significant speculation.

Comment: This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The [mre] should include **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include a mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CODE:

```
import seaborn as sns

x = [18.86,19.86,18.98,18.31,18.76,17.78,17.05,16.75]
ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

[image]

Distplot accepts Parameters
a Series, 1d-array, or list.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html for more detail.

Always follow official documents.